# Best way to get "average" value from the collection where crazy value can appear

Tags: statistics

Maybe there is an answer to my question, but my English is not ideal so maybe I just can't search properly :)
I have a collection of values where occasionally can appear a crazy value. For example values look like this:

```
23, 28, 22, 29, 32, 21, 26, 25, 27, 24, 1, 124, 745
```

Generally I need to get "average" value from this collection but the crazy values must be omitted. Do you have any ideas how to do it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier

Comment: I encourage you to check the spelling in your posts.  Careful spelling will help give Readers an impression that you are earnest in seeking their help, and many browsers have spell checkers built-in.

Answer (score 1):

The general class of statistics you want are called [robust statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics).  The simplest maximally robust statistic for central tendency is the median.  If this is too insensitive for you, you can try some of the other robust statistics listed in the Wikipedia plot summary for [central tendency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_tendency); applicable statistics there include the [truncated mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_mean) (of which the [interquartile mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_mean) is a special case), the [midhinge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midhinge), and the [trimean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimean).

The answer given by Mohammad Riazi-Kermani is an example of a truncated mean, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If by crazy value you mean an outlier, you may  drop the minimum and the maximum, or drop the top five percent and the button five percent and take the average of the rest of them.

For example in your data $$ 23, 28, 22, 29, 32, 21, 26, 25, 27, 24, 1, 124, 745 $$ you drop $1$and $745$ and $124$ which are outliers in comparison to the other items.

Answer (score 0):

"One way" is to omit outliers which are defined as values $1.5$ times the inter-quartile range below the first quartile or above the third quartile. This would be $1.5\cdot (30.5 -22.5) = 12$ and would therefore eliminate $1, 124$ and $745$.